# Why does my springboot security app always return 404 ErrorPageFilter error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, kerberos

Update: After set the loggin level to debug, this is what I got

[image]
I'm developing a springboot application with kerberos spegno authentication. But whenever user access the url protected by spring security it always return this 404 error

[image]

This is what I got from catalina.out

> 2020-05-15 22:45:59.122 ERROR 84750 --- [-nio-80-exec-10] o.s.b.w.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter : Cannot forward to error page for request [/404] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false

You can see my entire project [here](https://github.com/xuanlinh91/demo-kerberos-spegno), please point out my mistake and help me solve this problem
Thank you

Comment: set the log level to DEBUG in application.properties ( example , `logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG`). This would give more details. Update the question with exception details if you are unable to identify the cause

Comment: Hi @R.G thank for replying me
I add the debug logging level to spring properties like you said, Can you take a look at the the update information of my post?
I guess the problem is my browser does not send Authorization header so the SpegnoFilter is not working, right? I do all the browser setting needed for kerberos authentication intergrated though